# How do I display an image using IMG SRC that is within a massive block of PHP?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, image

I've been looking for the solution for this and I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't figure it out.  I'm basically querying for products in my database.  I've stored thumbnail images in a folder corresponding to the product_id.  The only thing I can't get to display is the image.  Please fill me in on where I'm going wrong.  Thanks a ton!

```
$products = get_products();

if (empty($products)) {
    echo '<p>No products to display yet</p>'; 
} else {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<img src="../uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $product_id; ?>/<?php echo $product_id; ?>.jpg", <p><a href="view_product.php?product_id=', $product['id'], '">', $product['name'], '</a><br/>', $product['description'], '...<br/>
        </p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: C'mon homie, i actually just realized that we were supposed to accept answers on my last question (somebody else told me)...so i started doing it.  Will always do in the future for sure.  (I plan to be on here a lot).  Help me out.

Comment: FYI, another way to more be part of the StackOverflow community is to pick a non-auto-generated username. If you go to [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/559672/user559672), you can click edit and give yourself both a name and (through gravatar) an avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to tell without seeing the array structure that it returns, but if the image filename is just the product Id, then this should work.

You were trying to do string concatenation with a comma?  DOes that work?

String concatenation has to be done like:

```
$str = 'Text'.$variable.'More Text';
```

Try this:

```
 if (empty($products)) {
            echo '<p>No products to display yet</p>'; 
        } else {
            foreach ($products as $product) {
             ?>
                 <img src="../uploads/thumbs/<?=$product['id']?>/<?=$product['id']?>.jpg" />
                 <p><a href="view_product.php?product_id=<?=$product['id']?>"><?=$product['name']?></a>
                 <br/>
                 <?=$product['description']?>
                 <br/>                
              <?php
            }
        }
```

Definitely accept all answers that are correct, or helped you.

What you were doing wrong:

```
echo '<img src="../uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $product_id; ?>/<?php echo $product_id; ?>.jpg"
```

YOu have to specify array keys like $product['id'] not $product_id, It looks like that variable does not exist.

Edit:
Variables inside Strings:

```
//Concatenation:
echo '<img src="'.$pathtoimage.'" />';

//In string parsing:
echo "<img src=\"{$pathtoimage}\" />";

//Or break out of php like this:

<img src="<?php echo $pathtoimage;?>" />
//or the shorter:
<img src="<?=$pathtoimage?>" />
```

Comment: TRY? what about **to understand**?!

Comment: sorry if this is a dump question (beginner).  but why the <?=$product['description']?>    is that just the same as <?php echo $product['description']; ?>

Comment: lol - damn Colonel...chill...I'm TRYIN' to understand.  i really am.

Comment: It's a short way of echoing variables, You really have three options, I will put them in my post above:

Comment: NO Problem, take a look at my edit above for some more ways of accomplishing the same thing.